# EmberJs - Bubble up action from modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a couple of nested routes. In one of them it's possible to open a modal (which is attached to another outlet called modal).

When the user enters the text and clicks Ok, it's sent an action ('valueUpdated') to the MyrouteChildController. However, I also need to bubble this event up to MyrouteController, but it's not working. I tried returning true in the action handler and also manually calling @send.

If I call the MyrouteChildController's action from its own template it works.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lotinaw/edit?html,js,output

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only you can `inject` services in `components` and `controllers` in Ember by using `Ember.inject.service()` but you might also inject controllers and send actions to them using `Ember.inject.controller()` and then proceed with

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    mycontroller: Ember.inject.controller('mycontroller'),
    funcUsingControllerToSendAction(args){
        let mycontroller = this.get('mycontroller');
        mycontroller.send('myaction',args);
    }
});
```

This would allow you to send action with arguments to the other controller context.

Comment: Be careful when injecting controllers, if they're not the controller for a parent route and you haven't visited that specific route, it'll be uninitialized.

Comment: @locks is there any way to check whether controller is initialized? Would the check `mycontroller instanceof Ember.Controller` be valid to check whether the controller is initialized?

Comment: Nope. It will be an instance of Controller, because you injected it.

Comment: @locks Is there any difference in that? Shouldn't instance of controller be initialized to become instance? I know that might sound not right but you say that the controller might be uninitialized if the route is not visited yet. As i understand initialization itself happens when the `init()` method is called on the class. After this the controller becomes an instance and `mycontroller instanceof Ember.Controller` should be the right thing to check. What am i missing here?

Comment: It won't have a model, nor any properties you might have set up setupController, because you haven't visited the route.